# How to get only the diagonal of the matrix from these loops?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I have the following code for a 8 dimensional empirical copula that creates a 8d matrix but I only need the diagonal of the matrix which is named EC in this code. Since this code is very slow, is there anyway that I can get "EC" without computing all of "ecop"?

```
function EC = ecopula8d(x)

[m n] = size(x);

y = sort(x);

for r=1:m
        for q=1:m
            for p=1:m
                for o=1:m
                    for l=1:m
                        for k=1:m
                            for j=1:m
                                for i=1:m
             ecop(i,j,k,l,o,p,q,r) = sum( (x(:,1)<=y(i,1)).*(x(:,2)<=y(j,2)).*(x(:,3)<=y(k,3)).*(x(:,4)<=y(l,4))...
             .*(x(:,5)<=y(o,5)).*(x(:,6)<=y(p,6)).*(x(:,7)<=y(q,7)).*(x(:,8)<=y(r,8)) )/(m+1);
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
end

for i=1:m
EC(i,1)=ecop(i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i);
end
```

Comment: Hm. This looks like a logical expression which could definitely be sped up. Could you describe with your own words what you were trying to implement here?

Comment: Without knowledge about what this should do I'd say: As the loop does not depend on its calculations: Just replace all of the variables  `j,k,l,o,p,q,r` with `i`, get rid of your outer loops and change `ecop(i,j,k,l,o,p,q,r)` to `EC(i,1)`

Comment: @knedlsepp I am trying to find only the diagonal of ecop which is called EC and ecop is the empirical copula which is detailed in here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28probability_theory%29#Empirical_copulas

Comment: @knedlsepp you mean ecop calculation is wrong?

Comment: as knedlsepp have suggested just use ecop(i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can employ a completely vectorized solution with [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
EC = squeeze(sum(all(bsxfun(@le,x,permute(y,[3 2 1])),2),1))/(m+1)
```

The magic here happens with the use of [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) enabling us to go full throttle on [`vectorization`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html).

Here's a benchmarking test to compare this approach and the [other partially  vectorized approach with `bsxfun`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29481919/3293881) on runtime efficiency -

```
x = rand(2000,2000);
y = sort(x);
m = size(x,1);

%// Warm up tic/toc.
for k = 1:100000
    tic(); elapsed = toc();
end

disp('----------- With completely vectorized solution')
tic
EC1 = squeeze(sum(all(bsxfun(@le,x,permute(y,[3 2 1])),2),1))/(m+1);
toc, clear EC1

disp('----------- With partial vectorized solution')
tic
for i = 1:m
    EC2(i,1) = sum(all(bsxfun(@le, x, y(i,:)), 2), 1)/(m+1);
end
toc
```

The runtimes thus obtained were -

```
----------- With completely vectorized solution
Elapsed time is 2.883594 seconds.
----------- With partial vectorized solution
Elapsed time is 4.752508 seconds.
```

One can pre-allocate for the other partially vectorized approach -

```
EC2 = zeros(m,1);
for i = 1:m
    EC2(i,1) = sum(all(bsxfun(@le, x, y(i,:)), 2), 1)/(m+1);
end
```

The runtimes thus obtained weren't that different though -

```
----------- With completely vectorized solution
Elapsed time is 2.963835 seconds.
----------- With partial vectorized solution
Elapsed time is 4.620455 seconds.
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't checked if your initial computation is correct (as in *compared your implementation with the wikipedia article's formula*), but your code should be equivalent to:

```
[m n] = size(x);
y = sort(x);
for i = 1:m
    EC(i,1) = sum(all(bsxfun(@le, x, y(i,:)), 2), 1)/(m+1);
end
```

Comment: @Fred: Yes, I simplified it in two steps: First we realize that every computation of `ecop(i,j,k,l,o,p,q,r)` except for `ecop(i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i)` with `i = 1:m` is absolutely useless, as these values are never used. So I remove all but the `i` loop and use `i` instead of the variable names `j,k,l,o,p,q,r`. Then it's just a matter of replacing the `<=` with `bsxfun(@le` and the products `.*` with `all`.

Answer (score 0):

Once of the approaches I would use is to convert N-D array into square 2-D(if possible) and then simply extract diagonal term as they should be equal in both cases:

```
EC=diag(reshape(ecop,size1,size2));
```

I would suggest to try use Python because *numpy* has really nice and efficient linear algebra package to deal with N-D arrays. Matlab is pretty slow in adding and updating its libraries.

Comment: The problematic code is not the extraction of the diagonal elements, but rather the generation of the humongous N-D array, which is not needed at all! Also the approach you are suggesting doesn't even work!